# How do I get ASP.NET to route a controller properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Sales saleRecord = new Sales();
        var result = saleRecord.GetSalesOrderHeader((int)id);


        return View(result);
    }
```

However if I browse to /ControllerName/Details/5 I get this error:

> "Server Error in '/' Application. - The view 'details' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

The strange thing is that if I use ASP.NET Scaffolding to generate a view, the Details part of that works fine. It's basically the same code I have above as well.

Here's my RouteConfig.cs, if that's relevant:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

So why is that the scaffolding controller works fine, without having anything specific added to RouteConfig, yet my controller Details method is not working?

Comment: Where are you placing the view? Are you placing it in one of the locations specified by the error message? By the way, your route to your action method seems to be working (you need to change the title of your question).

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your action before you return the view does it get triggered? It may be that the view doesn't have the correct name or is in the wrong location

Comment: Make sure your view is in the relevant directory. MVC is very particular about this. Example: If your controller is called `SalesController`, make sure the view is inside `Views/Sales`.

Comment: Did you run the project before trying to navigate to the route?

Answer (score 2):

There should be more detail in error that what locations have been searched. Did you put break point in controller and checked if its being hit?

try

```
return View((object)result);
```

instead of

```
return View(result)
```

cause its calling overload View(string viewName)

If this doesn't work, try to specify viewName explicitly like this:

```
return View("ViewName", name);
```

Additionally, check your folder structure. MVC looks for views (like Index) under the views folder but they also have to be under a folder named after their controller (except partial views).

Comment: Hi, I've figured out the problem, I wasn't aware the Details page needed to exist as a file, thanks!